# Classes of computatinal problems

Tags: complexity-theory

I am interested in all know classes of Computatinal problems. The [Wikipedia article on computational problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_problem) types is incomplete. Some of the known classes are:

1- Decision problem such as 3SAT

2- Search problem such Factoring search problem

3- Function problem such as finding a second Hamiltonian cycle on a cubic graph (given some Hamiltonian cycle) which in TFNP

4- Optimization problem such as maximum independent set problem

5- Uniqueness problem such as Unique SAT problem

6- Another solution problem such as finding a second Hamiltonian cycle on a general graph (given some Hamiltonian cycle) which is in NP

7- Counting problem such as counting perfect matchings in bipartite graphs

8- Promise problem such as [finding solution of SAT](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~Vijay.Vazirani/Unique.pdf) under the promise that it has a unique solution

9- Inverse problem such as [Inverse 3SAT](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-45138-9_28)

10- Extendibility problem such as [edge precoloring extension problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24901/hard-extendability-problems) on bipartite graphs

11- Parity problem such as Parity-SAT

> What other types of computational problems should be added to the above list?

P.S. Some of the above can be cast as decision problem such as optimization problems.

Comment: This looks too broad to me.  Any community votes?

Comment: And too list-y.